# CoreDNS pods stuck in ContainerCreating - Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, devops, coredns

I am still new to Kubernetes and I was trying to set up a cluster on bare metal servers according to the official docu.

Right now I am running a one worker and one master node configuration, but I am struggling to run all the pods once the cluster initializes. The main problem is the coredns pods, that are stuck in the ContainerCreating state.

```
  NAMESPACE     NAME                                     READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-78fcd69978-4vtsp                 0/1     ContainerCreating   0          5s
kube-system   coredns-78fcd69978-wtn2c                 0/1     ContainerCreating   0          12h
kube-system   etcd-dcpoth24213118                      1/1     Running             4          12h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-dcpoth24213118            1/1     Running             0          12h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-dcpoth24213118   1/1     Running             0          12h
kube-system   kube-proxy-8282p                         1/1     Running             0          12h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-dcpoth24213118            1/1     Running             0          12h
kube-system   weave-net-6zz2j                          2/2     Running             0          12h
```

After checking the logs I've noticed this error. The problem is I don't really know what the error is refering to.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               19s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-78fcd69978-4vtsp to dcpoth24213118
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  13s                kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to set up sandbox container "2521c9dd723f3fc50b3510791a8c35cbc9ec19768468eb3da3367274a4dfcbba" network for pod "coredns-78fcd69978-4vtsp": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "coredns-78fcd69978-4vtsp_kube-system" network: error getting ClusterInformation: Get "https://[10.43.0.1]:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: no route to host, failed to clean up sandbox container "2521c9dd723f3fc50b3510791a8c35cbc9ec19768468eb3da3367274a4dfcbba" network for pod "coredns-78fcd69978-4vtsp": networkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod "coredns-78fcd69978-4vtsp_kube-system" network: error getting ClusterInformation: Get "https://[10.43.0.1]:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: no route to host]
  Normal   SandboxChanged          10s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

I've running the kuberenetes cluster behind a corporate proxy. I've set the environmental variables as follows.

```
export https_proxy=http://proxyIP:PORT
export http_proxy=http://proxyIP:PORT
export HTTP_PROXY="${http_proxy}"
export HTTPS_PROXY="${https_proxy}"
export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,master_node_IP,worker_node_IP,10.0.0.0/8,10.96.0.0/16

[root@dcpoth24213118 ~]# kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE     NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP                  12h
kube-system   kube-dns     ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   12h


[root@dcpoth24213118 ~]# ip r s
default via 6.48.248.129 dev eth1
6.48.248.128/26 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 6.48.248.145
10.32.0.0/12 dev weave proto kernel scope link src 10.32.0.1
10.155.0.0/24 via 6.48.248.129 dev eth1
10.228.0.0/24 via 6.48.248.129 dev eth1
10.229.0.0/24 via 6.48.248.129 dev eth1
10.250.0.0/24 via 6.48.248.129 dev eth1
```

I've got weave network plugin installed. The issue is that I cannot create any other pods, all will get stuck in the ContainerCreating state.

I've run out of ideas how to fix it. Can someone give me a hint ?

Comment: any luck? I'm in the same boat right now

Comment: @MattCamp Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: yes and no.. it ended up being something wrong with the CNI paths on Arch. I eventually switched to using [k0s](https://k0sproject.io/) which mostly fixed things.. but there were some other tweaks I might have had to do.. not all of them I have fully documented and so I can't really provide a full on answer :-(

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but here's what fixed this problem for me, in 2023. In my case it was flannel's fault.

BAD: (many tutorials use this link)

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`

GOOD:

`kubectl apply -f https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/releases/latest/download/kube-flannel.yml`

Before: (Container creating)

```
k get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                                           READY   STATUS              RESTARTS      AGE
kube-flannel   pod/kube-flannel-ds-6krkg                      1/1     Running             0             11s
kube-flannel   pod/kube-flannel-ds-pgkzz                      1/1     Running             0             11s
kube-flannel   pod/kube-flannel-ds-sr9pt                      1/1     Running             0             11s
kube-system    pod/coredns-5dd5756b68-vjx9g                   0/1     ContainerCreating   0             86m
kube-system    pod/coredns-5dd5756b68-vvg2m                   0/1     ContainerCreating   0             86m
kube-system    pod/etcd-k8s-controlplane                      1/1     Running             1 (66m ago)   87m
kube-system    pod/kube-apiserver-k8s-controlplane            1/1     Running             1 (66m ago)   87m
kube-system    pod/kube-controller-manager-k8s-controlplane   1/1     Running             1 (66m ago)   86m
kube-system    pod/kube-proxy-dbmjq                           1/1     Running             0             85m
kube-system    pod/kube-proxy-lvtmt                           1/1     Running             0             85m
kube-system    pod/kube-proxy-n9q89                           1/1     Running             1 (66m ago)   86m
kube-system    pod/kube-scheduler-k8s-controlplane            1/1     Running             1 (66m ago)   87m
```

after the new flannel:

```
k get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   pod/coredns-5dd5756b68-5b7hb                   1/1     Running             0          10m
kube-system   pod/coredns-5dd5756b68-czzrk                   1/1     Running             0          10m
kube-system   pod/etcd-k8s-controlplane                      1/1     Running             2          10m
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-k8s-controlplane            1/1     Running             2          10m
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-k8s-controlplane   1/1     Running             2          10m
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-5xcvh                           1/1     Running             0          9m22s
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-ftbhc                           1/1     Running             0          10m
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-lkdb6                           1/1     Running             0          9m28s
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-k8s-controlplane            1/1     Running             2          10m
```